# Authentication errors sending mail in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to send a mail using laravel but am getting this error :

"Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required"

This is my mail.php file

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

This is where I send my mail from (routes.php)- for testing though.

```
Route::get('/send', function(){
  mail::send('Email.signup', [], function ($message) {
    $message->to('mymail@gmail.com', 'example_name');
    $message->subject('Welcome!');
    $message->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');
  });

});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well, do you *have* environment variables with your username and password named as suggested in the `mail.php` file?

Comment: Where do I get the username and password from?

Comment: From your mailgun account?